# What to do to be a SAP Consultant?

Tags: untagged

Almost newbie to the SAP world, and newly graduating from the Computer Engineering department.

Comment: Most consultants can write clear questions and answers, you might consider working on those skills too.

Comment: if English isn't his first language, @Chopper3, then it wasn't written too badly

Comment: Especially if he/she won't be working in an English speaking location.

Comment: SAP is still littered with German anyway! So English aint too much of a problem... Oh and my advice... Don't go there.. I do SAP consulting, and I am starting to go grey and bald... and alcoholic ;-)

Answer (score 4):

SAP is *complicated*, there are innumerable horror stories floating around the net.

This isn't something you can take a course in and suddenly start making big bucks. People may try but the potential for screwing something up is high, and then you're name is mud.

I'd recommend getting some real world experience first, ideally in a medium to large company that uses SAP. If you've been on the receiving end of consultants, seen the good and bad, and had to deal with the day to day side of a system then you will be a much more attractive proposition for someone looking for an SAP consultant.

The alternative is to get hired by an established SAP consultancy, many of the major IT consultancy firms will hire new graduates and provide the necessary training and enable you to get the relevant experience, without the worry of having to find consulting gigs. The downside is you may be thrown at a problem along with many other new consultants and find yourself not really in a position to do anything but there merely to generate revenue for the firm.

Answer (score 1):

Althought this may differ depending on the area where you work, many SAP consultants I know have started doing a non-SAP job for a company that runs SAP.

If you want to be a SAP Netweaver Administrator, apply for a junior systems administrator job at a company that runs SAP.  If you want to be an ABAP developer apply for a generic developer job and if you want to be a Functional Consultant go for a Business Analysis or Systems Analysis job.

Like Chris has said, SAP is a very complex system and becoming proficient in it requires a lot of patience and a bit of luck.

SAP courses are expensive and I would not recommend spending your own money on it.  A SAP certification does not guarantee that you will get a SAP job as the market are often looking for experienced consultants.  Some companies are willing to take on junior people and usually realise that these people will have to be trained.

If you are interested in SAP [SDN](http://sdn.sap.com) has some good references.  It is also possible to download and install a trial version of SAP, but this will only be useful to you if you're interested in either BASIS administration or ABAP programming.  None of the core modules are shipped with the trial.

You also need to be sure that the type of job that SAP will land you is really what you want.  Usually it is big corporates or government agencies that can make use of an expensive ERP like SAP.

Answer (score 1):

I've only personally met 2 people who were able to come straight out of school and go into any kind of professional consulting - and they were coming with lots of work experience while in school, research projects, etc.

I came out of school with work experience, went into support, and then into consulting.

For ***any*** tool the size of SAP, you're going to need a **LOT** of exposure to it before you try to do *any* consulting and explaining to others what they should be doing.

What you want to do is a good idea - but you need to work up to it, or you'll have your name dragged through the mud, and will likely not be better off than if you'd gone into a "normal" job first.

It's possible a consultancy group would hire you to be a SAP consultant with no experience, by in my experience, services positions like that all clamor for 3-10 years of on-the-job work related to the role.

Answer (score 1):

I've never worked with SAP but don't believe anyone fresh out of school is ready for any kind of IT consulting work, especially when that person admits to being a newbie in the field. Get yourself a decade or so working with it first.

Here's a simple rule: If you need to ask, you're nowhere near ready.

Answer (score 0):

Which area of SAP would you be interested in?

- Development (programming)
- System administration (BASIS)
- Architect
- Other

If BASIS you can ask lots of questions in http://sapbasis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Best method: Get hired by SAP (= free training, good reputation), then become a consultant after a few years. I personally know five cases where this worked very well.